# Radio buttons not changing database in firefox but they do in chrome, why?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cross-browser

I have a remote form which contains 3 radio button tags, each will change the DB accordingly. This works perfectly fine in chrome but when I switch to FF the radio get checked and all but the DB does not change at all.

This is the form in my view.

```
<%= form_tag ("deal_status"), :remote => true, :class => "deals_status" do %>

    <%= hidden_field_tag 'deal_id', d.id.to_s %>

    <%= radio_button_tag( :state, "won"+d.id.to_s, d.state == "won", :class => "toggle-btn-left toggle-btn", :value =>"won") %>
    <%= label_tag  'state_won'+d.id.to_s, "won", :class=>"btn" %>   

    <%= radio_button_tag :state, "lost"+d.id.to_s, d.state == 'lost', :class => "toggle-btn-center toggle-btn",:value => "lost" %>
    <%= label_tag  'state_lost'+d.id.to_s, "lost",:class=>"btn" %>

    <%= radio_button_tag :state, "pending"+d.id.to_s, d.state == 'pending',:class => "toggle-btn-right toggle-btn", :value => "pending" %>
    <%= label_tag  'state_pending'+d.id.to_s, "pending",:class=>"btn" %>

<% end %>
```

this the js that does the submitting

```
$("body").on("change", "form :radio", function(){
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

and this is the controller's action :

```
  def deal_status

    deal_id = params[:deal_id]
    d = Deal.find_by_id(deal_id)
    d.state = params[:state]
    d.save

    @deal_id = deal_id
    @deal = d

      respond_to do |format|
      format.js 

    end
  end
```

Comment: Just a guess: Put the `submit` call in a `setTimeout`, so that the submission happens after the change event was completely processed.

Comment: Like this ? ` $("body").on("change", "form :radio", function(){
  setTimeout(function() {
       $(this).closest("form").submit();
}, 5000);
 });`

Comment: Inside the callback, `this` won't refer to the element. You have to assign it to a variable first: `var self = this; setTimeout(function() { $(self)... }, 1);`. But apart from that, yes. Just use a small number for the timeout. You don't want to wait 5 seconds before submitting the form, it should be submitted immediately, but after the change event was handled. Choose `0` or `10`.

Comment: I did this ` $("body").on("change", "form :radio", function(){
  setTimeout(function() {
   $(self).closest("form").submit();
  });
 });` and the the form is not even submitting. Added selft as you said on top of this.

Comment: You still need to pass a duration as second argument to `setTimeout` I believe.

Comment: I did that too, still didn't work..

Comment: Mmmh. As I said it was just a guess. Is the data not sent at all? Have you checked the network traffic?

Comment: when using this method.. nothing.. before 304 not modified error.

Comment: Maybe you did something wrong and the code is not even executed properly? [Have a look here to learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and check the console for errors.